# conditions for algebra cohomology finiteness

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A=\bigoplus\limits_{n\geq 0}A_n$ be a graded (unital associative) ring, say an algebra over a field with finite dimensional graded components and $A_0$ semisimple. Are there reasonable conditions on $A$ guaranteeing that $Ext^i(L,L')$ is finite dimensional for irreducible graded modules $L$, $L'$? Of course, $A$ being left Noetherian is sufficient, but it is not necessary and I wonder if there is a standard property of $A$ weaker than being Noetherian that would imply that.

Comment: By "algebra" I guess you mean "unital associative algebra".

Comment: associative would be enough since a semisimple associative algebra automatically has a unit.